# Finding the sign of each permutations

Tags: number-theory, permutations

How to find the sign of each of the following permutations?

1,  (1 2 3 4 5)(8 7 6)(10 11)

2,  (1 3 5 7 9 11)(2 4 6 8 10)

3,  (1 2)(3 4)(5 6 7 8)(9 10)

4,  (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)(1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2)

Help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any cycle of length $p$ can be decomposed in a product of $p-1$ transpositions. The signature of permutation has the same parity as the number of transpositions, in any decomposition as a product of transpositions only. Now let's apply this:

1. First cycle is of length 5, second of length 3, third of length 2: 4+2+1 = 7, it's odd.
2. 6,5: 5+4=9 -> odd
3. 2,2,4,2: 1+1+3+1=6 -> even
4. 8,8: 7+7=14 -> even

Answer (score 0):

HINT: **Every permutation can be expressed as a product of transpositions.** 
For instance $(a\,\,\,b\,\,\, c\,\,\, d)=(a \,\,\, d)(a \,\,\, c)(a \,\,\, b)$
Can you rewrite your permutations in this way?
*Next*: Permutations with even (*odd*) number of disjoint transpositions have sign +1 (*-1*)